# Why is only the last append valid when creating node outside of a function?

Tags: javascript

```
let items = document.querySelector('.items');    // class of ul tag
let $li = document.createElement("li");

function add(item) {
  $li.textContent = item;
  items.append($li);
}

add('soup');
add('shampoo');
```

If a node is created with createElement in the function, it is reflected normally. However, I am curious about the detailed reason why only the last element of append is added when a li node is created outside of the function like now.

Comment: You only create a single `<li>` at the start of your script. And every time you run `add`, you change its text and move it to the end of the list _(When you use `.append(x)` and `x` is already in the DOM, it won't be duplicated, it will be moved in the DOM)_. Instead, move your `let $li = ...` line inside the `add` function, to create a new one every time

Answer (score 2):

You should create the li node each time inside the function. Otherwise it will have reference to the old node and update only the innerHTML for that node.

```
let items = document.querySelector('.items');    // class of ul tag


function add(item) {
  let $li = document.createElement("li");
  $li.textContent = item;
  items.append($li);
}

add('soup');

add('shampoo');
```